# Why is perfect passive participle from 'enuntio' - 'enunciatus'?

Tags: etymology, new-latin, verbs

In my dictionary *enuntio* is first conjugation verb,

*enuntio, avi, are*

Now in Spinoza there came up this word - 'enunciatum', which is said to be (source - Wictionary) coming from *enuntio*, as alternative form of *'enuntiatus'*, Perfect passive participle of ēnuntiō.

I haven't noticed such a changes before, is it common in new Latin?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is very common, in fact. In Medieval and later Latin, both C and T before I and E (and thus also AE and OE) softened the dentals (probably into /ts/ but perhaps even /tʃ/, English's "ch" sound.

This then led a number of places where in Latin there was a T to turn into a C, such as *racio* for *ratio* or *vicium* for *vitium*, leading to the derivative *vice*.

Many of the changes are detailed under Medieval Latin orthography guides, such as [Mantello & Rigg's](https://books.google.com/books?id=Bb32Th4WAK0C&pg=PA79#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: In current ecclesiastical pronunciation, *c* before e-i-oe-ae becomes /tʃ/ while *t* before *i* + vowel (e.g. -tio, -tium, -tia) becomes /ts/.

Comment: In Italian the word is *enunciato* (with /tʃ/, means ‘statement’); similarly, *renuntiare* gave *rinunziare* (with /ts/, formal written language, not used any longer in speech) and the more common *rinunciare*. To the contrary, *vitium* gave *vizio* (with /ts/) and *ratio/rationem* gave *ragione*.

Answer (score 4):

The usual school pronunciation of Latin in Germany is that ci + vowel and ti + vowel are both realised as /tsi/.